# SQL server 2016 external data source - Incorrect syntax near 'external'

Tags: sql-server, azure, windows-server-2016, external-tables

I have a SQL server 2016 with a DB running on it. The SQL server runs on a Windows server 2016 as a VM through Azure.

Within that DB I'd like to create an external data source that reference a DB on another server remote server.

I have created the necessary credentials.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE EXTERNALDS WITH 
(TYPE = HADOOP,
 LOCATION = N'***',
 CREDENTIAL = Credentials,
 DATABASE_NAME = N'***'
   );
```

Executing this query returns the following error message;

> Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.

Comment: I'm betting that isn't the exact statement you tried to execute? Is the word `EXTERNAL` located elsewhere in your *actual* statement. Or perhaps your original statement was missing a `'` somewhere.

Comment: You're right, that's not the exact statement. I replaced the values of location and database_name with three stars. I can't really see where I've missed a '... The word EXTERNAL is not located anywhere else in the entire actual statement.

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION` and double check your on a 2016 or better SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU7-GDR) (KB4057119) - 13.0.4466.4 (X64)   Dec 22 2017 11:25:00   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)